# Is there a good way to use Console.ReadKey for choosing between values without doing a lot of conversion between types?

Tags: c#, types, console

Im using Console.ReadKey() to choose from a number of options that varies from time to time.
Before this initial code snippet there is a for loop that counts occurances into counter variable of type int.

The point is to use Console.ReadKey() to get an int.

```
int choice = ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine("");

if (choice < counter)
{
    mail.to = result[counter-1].email;
}
```

By using the following methods

```
static int ReadKey()
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo choice = Console.ReadKey();
    char convertedchoice = choice.KeyChar;
    string convertedchoice2 = convertedchoice.ToString();
    int result = TryInt(convertedchoice2);
    return result;
}

static int TryInt(string totry)
{
    while (true)
    {
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(totry, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you need to enter a number. Try again.");
    }
}
```

I tried using ToString() but this was the way that it would let me do it in the end.
So this looks kind of inneffective to me and hence I would really appreciate some guidance as what to do differently?

Edit:

I ended up with a combination of all the good answers below. Thanks alot guys.

```
static int ReadKey()
{
    while (true)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo choice = Console.ReadKey();
        if (char.IsDigit(choice.KeyChar))
        {
            int answer = Convert.ToInt32(choice.KeyChar);
            return answer - 48; //-48 because 0 is represented in unicode by 48 and 1 by 49 etc etc
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nSorry, you need to input a number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a menu system with choices 0..9 this is reasonably OK. Not for reading larger numbers though.

Your whole checking logic can be made a lot easier with char.IsDigit() :

```
if char.IsDigit(convertedchoice)
{
  int result = convertedchoice - '0';    // char1 - char2 = int, in this case in 0..9
  return result;
}
else ...
```

Comment: the use of char.IsDigit() was an eye opener for me beoynd this problem. Thanks for doing preemptive work on questions from me!

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `Convert.ToInt32(choice.KeyChar);` directly.

That would simplify it a bit.

Comment: That just gives me the error.

'char' does not contain a definition for 'ToInt' and no extension method 'ToInt' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found

Comment: It should be int result = Convert.ToInt32(choice.KeyChar);  I will update my answer to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to simplify your code, but for a start try to avoid putting everything into a variable.  In general, things like:

```
(a + b + c) / 2
```

are much easier to read than things like:

```
int A_plus_B = a + b
int A_plus_B_plus_C = A_plus_B + c
int answer = A_plus_B_plus_C / 2
```

With this in mind, you could write:

```
static int ReadKey()
{
    while (true)
    {
        char ch = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(ch.toString(), out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but my professor actually prefers us to write like that for clarity when turning in assignments.

Comment: That's not clarity.  And FYI, when you post homework, you're supposed to tag it as such.